# Android source code git download error

Tags: android, git

I am getting the following error when trying to download the gingerbread source code using git:

```
$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest 
project .repo/manifests/

fatal: Needed a single revision
invalid upstream 7ed9d5cc82ab675d37e67dd558e010c6d96c44c5^1

fatal: manifest 'default.xml' not available
fatal: manifest default.xml not found
```

Answer (score 4):

I have found the root cause of this problem. It was there due to corrupt repo. I removed .repo directory, installed repo again and it worked fine. 
Thanks.